# How to convert Pandas Dataframe to list of dict for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Is there any possible way to convert pandas Dataframe to dict with list for each row?

```
                      Open   High  Low   Close  

2021-12-15 12:30:00  1.9000  1.91  1.86  1.8850        
2021-12-15 13:30:00  1.8881  1.95  1.88  1.9400     
2021-12-15 14:30:00  1.9350  1.95  1.86  1.8956
```

The output I want

```
{x:2021-12-15 12:30:00, y:\[1.9000,1.91,1.86,1.8850\]}

{x:2021-12-15 13:30:00, y:\[1.8881,1.95,1.88,1.9400\]}  

{x:2021-12-15 14:30:00, y:\[1.9350,1.95,1.86,1.8956\]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
dictt=list(zip(df.index,df[['Open','High','Low','Close']].values.tolist()))
final =[{'x':i[0], 'y':i[1]} for i in dictt]
```

or without loop:

```
df['y']=df[['Open','High','Low','Close']].values.tolist()
final = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'x'})[['x','y']].to_dict('records')
```

**Output**:

```
[
    {
        "x":"2021-12-15 12:30:00",
        "y":[
            1.9,
            1.91,
            1.86,
            1.885
        ]
    },
    {
        "x":"2021-12-15 13:30:00",
        "y":[
            1.8881,
            1.95,
            1.88,
            1.94
        ]
    },
    {
        "x":"2021-12-15 14:30:00",
        "y":[
            1.935,
            1.95,
            1.86,
            1.8956
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Its working but can we do without using loop?

Comment: Probably yes. Let me check.

Comment: getting error TypeError: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'names'

Comment: Weird... try this: `final = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'x'})[['x','combine_col']].to_dict('records')
`

Comment: We are trying to convert the index name to "x".

Comment: now also not working AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'rename'

Comment: `final = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'x'})[['x','combine_col']].to_dict('records')`

Comment: KeyError: "['combine_col'] not in index"

Comment: okey, please check edited answer again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a dataframe to a list of dict,you simply need to specify **orient='index'** ... So in your case if:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'o':[1,2,3],'l':[4,5,6],'x':[7,8,9]},index=['t1','t2','t3'])
```

then you can do:

```
[{'x':k,'y':list(v.values())} for k,v in df.to_dict(orient='index').items()]
```

or also:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x:list(x[df.columns]), axis=1))
list(df2.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'x',0:'y'}).to_dict(orient='index').values())
```

Either results to:

```
[{'x': 't1', 'y': [1, 4, 7]},
 {'x': 't2', 'y': [2, 5, 8]},
 {'x': 't3', 'y': [3, 6, 9]}]
```

Comment: Yes.. But want to show the result without using any loop

Comment: ok, added one "without" loops... Note that complexity wise you always will do something for all the elements. The point of avoiding *for* loops is that the computer finds it difficult to optimize, I think the first one-liner is the pythonic way to go

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.apply(lambda ss:ss.tolist(),axis=1).reset_index().set_axis(['x','y'],axis=1)\
    .apply(lambda ss:ss.to_dict(),axis=1)
```

output：

```
{'x': '2021-12-15 12:30:00', 'y': [1.9, 1.91, 1.86, 1.885]}
{'x': '2021-12-15 13:30:00', 'y': [1.8881, 1.95, 1.88, 1.94]}
{'x': '2021-12-15 14:30:00', 'y': [1.935, 1.95, 1.86, 1.8956]}
```